# Webclient Junit test for specific status code

Tags: junit, spring-webclient

I have a webclient which takes a specific action for specific status code ..
How can i write a junit to cover that specific piece to increase code coverage ?

```
 return this.webClient.get()
                .uri(requestURL)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(xxxAuthServiceImpl.getAccessToken()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                    if (response.statusCode() == NOT_FOUND) {
                        LOGGER.error("data not found for the passed id");
                        return Mono.error(new EntityNotFoundException("data not found for the passed id"));
                    }
                    return Mono.error(new xxxAPIClientException());
                }).bodyToMono(Object.class)
                .onErrorMap(Predicate.not(EntityNotFoundException.class::isInstance), exception -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Error occurred while calling xxx search data by id api.", exception);
                    return new xxxAPIClientException(exception.getMessage());
                }).block();
```

My existing Junit Test Cases look like this:-

```
 @Test
    void testDataSearchById_Success() throws Exception {
        // set up
        when(responseSpec.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(Object.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(buildDataSearchResponse()[0]));
        // execute
        final Object dataSearchResponseById = xxxSearchClientImpl.dataSearchById(SAMPLE_TEST_API_URL);
        // assert
        assertNotNull(dataSearchResponseById);
    }

    /**
     * Tests data search by id method which calls xxx api and no data found error
     * occurs.
     * The method should throw EntityNotFoundException
     */
    @Test
    void testDataSearchById_Failure_EntityNotFoundException() {
        // execute and assert
        when(responseSpec.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        doThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class).when(responseSpec).bodyToMono(Object.class);
        assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () -> xxxSearchClientImpl.dataSearchById(SAMPLE_TEST_API_URL));
    }

    /**
     * Tests data search by id method which calls xxx api and an exception occurs.
     * The method should throw xxxAPIClientException
     */
    @Test
    void testDataSearchById_Failure_xxxAPIClientException() {
        // execute and assert
        when(responseSpec.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        doThrow(xxxAPIClientException.class).when(responseSpec).bodyToMono(Object.class);
        assertThrows(xxxAPIClientException.class, () -> xxxSearchClientImpl.dataSearchById(SAMPLE_TEST_API_URL));
    }
```

Comment: Best way is to test using mockwebserver. Look at this link -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientIntegrationTests.java. Also this one  : https://rieckpil.de/test-spring-webclient-with-mockwebserver-from-okhttp/

Comment: None worked.. somehow im not able to enter the status code checking block..

Comment: i tried to do something similar and able to see the code being covered. Can you please let me know if u still have the issue. : https://github.com/harryalto/reactive-springwebflux/blob/master/src/test/java/com/reactivespringwebflux/client/FamilyClientTest.java